# Blazor MAUI page update from a method changing a property

Tags: blazor, blazor-hybrid

I try to make a simple application to understand how to work correctly with async, but I'm stuck right at the beginning.
Here is the code

```
<div class="box1">
<button @onclick="ExecuteSync">Normal Execute</button>
<button>Async Execute</button>
<div class="textBox">
    @((MarkupString) text)
</div>
```

```
@code{
string text = "Display results";

void ExecuteSync()
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    text = "";
    Method1();
    watch.Stop();

    var elapsedTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    text += $"Method 1 execution time: {elapsedTime} ms";
}

private void Method1()
{
    text += "Method 1 execution STARTED<br>";
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    text += "Method 1 execution ENDED<br>";
}
```

}

When I run this code and click on the Normal Execute button I get the following result.
[image]

The issue I have is that all the text is displayed after 2 seconds. I was expecting the first line to be displayed immedialtely, and the rest of the text after 2 seconds.

I tried to add StateHasChanged before the Sleep of 2 seconds but it didn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?